# Cronjob not scheduling in Kubernetes

Tags: bash, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

Hi i'm new to this please someone help in this. thanks in advance
I want to schedule a job for deleting a pod for every 3 days in midnight.
Manually script is working fine but scheduling with crontab is not wokring.
note:- deployment is statefulset

```
#!/bin/bash
kubectl delete pod keycloak-server-0
```

gave permission to execute with `chmod +x <sh file name>`

scheduling script with cron
`00 00 */3 * * <path of the script>`

Comment: Try logging the cmd someplace to see what it returns. Like: `kubectl delete pod keycloak-server-0 >> /tmp/delete_pod.log`

Comment: log file is empty

Comment: Add `>> /tmp/delete_pod.log  2>&1` to the crontab entry (rather than in the script) and see if that's more informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figuredout what i did wrong in scheduling job.

while scheduling we need to specify the `**SHELL=/bin/sh`** and `**PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`** in cron.